# asp.net WebSocket keep alive after Action is done

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, sockets

In an asp.net core (5.0) web application, is it possible to keep the socket alive without having a infinite while loop? (`while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open`) If the loop is the only way to do that, isn't that very inefficient?

This is essentially what I would like to achieve

```cs
public class SocketController : Controller
{

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("Connect")]
  public async Task ConnectAsync()
  {
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
      var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
      SocketManager.registerSocket(User, webSocket);
      var outputBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pong"));
      await webSocket.SendAsync(outputBuffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    else
    {
      HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
  }

}
```

This seems to work but, it doesn't seem right

```cs
public class SocketController : Controller
{

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("Connect")]
  public async Task ConnectAsync()
  {
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
      var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
      // stuff
      while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open) ;
    }
    else
    {
      HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
  }

}
```

Minimal example to check socket closing:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:44331/Socket/Connect");
socket.onclose = function (err) {
    console.log("CLOSED");
    console.error(err);
};
```

If I remove the loop, the connection closes on the JS side, the moment the action finishes executing, output:

```
CLOSED
{
    isTrusted: true,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: false,
    code: 1006,
    composed: false,
    currentTarget: [WebSocket Object],
    defaultPrevented: false,
    eventPhase: 0,
    path: [],
    reason: "",
    returnValue: true,
    srcElement: [WebSocket Object],
    target: [WebSocket Object],
    timeStamp: 958.5999999998603,
    type: "close",
    wasClean: false
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using SignalR? (I've tried using "raw" WebSockets directly without SignalR, but there was too many edge-cases to handle and gotchas tripping me up that I gave-up and just let SignalR handle it all for me, and I don't regret that decision). Not to mention the difficulty in meaningfully unit-testing and integration-testing raw WebSocket code. Just sharing my experience.

Comment: @Dai This was my first time working with sockets in .net core (had a much easier time doing this in .net) so I figured I would try to learn how it fully works and go with signalr for now (mostly for self imporvement). But I'm beginning to think this was a mistake. From what I've already seen from signalr, my main concern is browser compatibility since I'm fairly certain it uses webpack.

Comment: I don't see how Webpack is involved at all... that's just a JavaScript build tool.

Comment: I was under the impression that signalr uses it to import some of its modules but I might had been mistaken

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket use ping/pong heartbeat to keepalive.

> A Ping frame may serve either as a keepalive or as a means to verify
> that the remote endpoint is still responsive.

But when the client gets a Ping, a Pong must be sent back to the server

> Upon receipt of a Ping frame, an endpoint MUST send a Pong frame in
> response, unless it already received a Close frame. It SHOULD respond
> with Pong frame as soon as is practical.

You can use `KeepAliveInterval` to set How frequently to send "ping" frames to the client to ensure proxies keep the connection open. The default is two minutes.

```
var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions() 
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
};

app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
```

In your code, `while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)` just check the state of websocket and it will not keep the websocket alive.

The server is not automatically informed when the client disconnects due to loss of connectivity. The server receives a disconnect message only if the client sends it, which can't be done if the internet connection is lost. If you want to take some action when that happens, set a timeout after nothing is received from the client within a certain time window.

Comment: If I don't use something to prolong the request, the connection just closes on the JS side (in a matter of ms, long before the 120 seconds are up). The `while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)` is not keeping the socket alive, a `await Task.Delay(-1)` works just as well, my question is why do we need to delay the action from completing and is there a way to avoid fully blocking a thread?

Thank you for the taking the time to post this answer.

Answer (score 0):

even if a bit late: The problem with your solution is in fact, that your `while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open);` does CPU-intensive polling and should be avoided.

However, i felt the same "problem" and this is currently my solution. The difference is, that the loop is only processed if something is received as the `await ws.ReceiveAsync` in the loop blocks.

```cs
private async static Task ReceiveUntilClosed(WebSocket ws)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

    var receiveResult = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        HandleRequestResult(ws, receiveResult); // Your receive method handle stuff (or sending)
        var receiveResult = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ws closing connection...");
    await ws.CloseAsync(
        receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
        receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
        CancellationToken.None);
    Console.WriteLine("ws connection closed");
}
```

The method is called inside the Connect like:

```cs
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("Connect")]
  public async Task ConnectAsync()
  {
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
      var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
      SocketManager.registerSocket(User, webSocket);
      ReceiveUntilClosed(webSocket); // Here
    }
    else
    {
      HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
  }
```

In my case i added also a cancel-token so i can active close the connection.

If somebody has a better solution, feel free the correct me :)